# Recognize audio vs video podcasts in iOS

Tags: ios, podcasts.app

When searching for podcasts in the official iOS app, is there a way to see which ones are audio vs video? Or filter the search?

Comment: File size will tell, Audio is usually not more than 5 Meg.

Comment: That may be true for an episode, but what about an entire podcast? To quickly see from the search result which ones are audio...

Comment: MP3, WAV, ALAC,

Comment: what? Where do you see that??